# How to display huge content in tooltip in IE11

Tags: jsp, internet-explorer, tooltip, internet-explorer-11, jquery-ui-tooltip

How can I display huge content(approximately 1200 letters)in a tooltip in IE11?

JSP CODE:

```
    <form:select path="product" class="tooltip" name="product" id="product" maxlength="16" title="${productListToolTip}" >
        <form:option value=""></form:option>
        <form:options items="${productList}"/>
    </form:select>
```

Currently, only 520 letters can be displayed in a tooltip in Internet Explorer, but it works fine with other browsers such as Firefox or Chrome.

I need to display an entire product list content in a tooltip, but in Internet Explorer, only 520 letters show; in Firefox or Chrome, we can display the complete list.

How can I override this behaviour in IE11?

Comment: Add the code to the question instead of as a comment. You can edit the question with the edit link. Also make sure to add the jsp tag.

Comment: This is specifically a measure you can't count on the spec that doesn't provide available solution to your problem. Either you clarify your problem to add additional detailed to poorly added paragraphs in your question o'er remove altogether.